# Custom select filter function based on a selector instead of column number?

Tags: filter, tablesorter, filterfunction

From the [docs](http://mottie.github.io/tablesorter/docs/index.html) I read that the `filter_functions` could be used as follows:

```
filter_functions: {
        // Add these options to the select dropdown (regex example)
        2 : {
          "A - D" : function(e, n, f, i) { return /^[A-D]/.test(e); },
          "E - H" : function(e, n, f, i) { return /^[E-H]/.test(e); },
          "I - L" : function(e, n, f, i) { return /^[I-L]/.test(e); },
          "M - P" : function(e, n, f, i) { return /^[M-P]/.test(e); },
          "Q - T" : function(e, n, f, i) { return /^[Q-T]/.test(e); },
          "U - X" : function(e, n, f, i) { return /^[U-X]/.test(e); },
          "Y - Z" : function(e, n, f, i) { return /^[Y-Z]/.test(e); }
        }
      }
```

This makes a custom filter function for the 3rd column. I wonder if it's possible to specify a selector, e.g. `.columnWithCoolFilteFunction` instead of the column number?

The reason is that I have multiple tables where some of the columns contain similar data - and thus should be filtered in the same way - but the column number might be 1 in one table and 5 in another.

I understand that one solution would be to initiate every table with its own options, but I really like to initiate every table the same way (less code, yay!).

Possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Right now that isn't possible, but I did have the same idea! You can track [this issue](https://github.com/Mottie/tablesorter/issues/237) for when this ever gets implemented.

But in the mean time, what you can do is set up the filter object before initializing the table:

```
var alphabetical = {
    "A - D" : function(e, n, f, i) { return /^[A-D]/.test(e); },
    "E - H" : function(e, n, f, i) { return /^[E-H]/.test(e); },
    "I - L" : function(e, n, f, i) { return /^[I-L]/.test(e); },
    "M - P" : function(e, n, f, i) { return /^[M-P]/.test(e); },
    "Q - T" : function(e, n, f, i) { return /^[Q-T]/.test(e); },
    "U - X" : function(e, n, f, i) { return /^[U-X]/.test(e); },
    "Y - Z" : function(e, n, f, i) { return /^[Y-Z]/.test(e); }
};

$("table").tablesorter({
    widgetOptions : {
        filter_functions: {
            0 : alphabetical
            2 : alphabetical
        }
    },
    // other options
});
```

And yes, you will have to initialize each table separately until then =(

Comment: Alright, too bad! I hope that the issue will be implemented somewhere in the future :)